# $1/\sinh^2z$ near real infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was looking at a  contour integration where the claim had been made that the following function $1/\sinh^2 z $ goes to zero along the following lines in complex plane $(-\infty, 0)$ to $(-\infty, i\pi)$ and $(\infty, 0)$ to $(\infty, i\pi)$ - both lines running parallel to the imaginary axis.

Now with $z= x + iy$, $1/\sinh^2{z}$ becomes $$\frac{1}{(\sinh^2x \cos^2y -\cosh^2x\sin^2y -2i\sinh x \cosh x \sin y \cos y)}$$

It's not obvious to me that this goes to $0$ when $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$, because of the opposing signs of the first two terms. It would be helpful if someone could clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$ \lvert \sinh{(x+iy)} \rvert^2 = \lvert \sinh{x}\cos{y}+i\cosh{x}\sin{y} \rvert^2 = \sinh^2{x}\cos^2{y}+\cosh^2{x}\sin^2{y}, $$
using that $\cosh{iy}=\cos{y}$ and so on, which can be written as
$$ \sinh^2{x}\cos^2{y}+\cosh^2{x}\sin^2{y} = \sinh^2{x}(1-\sin^2{y})+(1+\sinh^2{x})\sin^2{y}\\
 = \sinh^2{x}+\sin^2{y} $$
using the Pythagorean identities. This tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$, so $1/$ it will tend to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me if $e^{-\sinh^2 z}$ will also vanish at those places? I think it won't but I'm clearly out of touch.

Comment: But that's irrelevant, right? You've shown that $1/\sinh^2 z \rightarrow 0$ which would mean $e^{1/\sinh^2 z } \rightarrow 1$ but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: Actually there's a problem with this derivation. it shows that $|\sinh ^2 z|$ goes to $\infty$ but that doesn't imply $\sinh ^2 z$ goes to $\infty$. So it's unclear that $1/ \sinh^2 z$ should go to 0.

Comment: If $|w| \to \infty$, $e^{-w} \to 0$ if and only if $\operatorname{Re}{w} $ tends to $\infty$, since $|e^{-w}| = e^{-\operatorname{Re}{w}}$. The real part, as you calculated, can be simplified into $(\cos{2y}\cosh{2x}-1)/2$, but this is not positive at, for example, $y=\pi/2$, so $e^{-\sinh^2{z}}$ does not necessarily tend to zero.

Comment: For complex $w$, $w \to 0 \iff |w| \to 0$, essentially by definition.